# My Stored Procedures Does Not Work

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

**Find out the head of school by inputting the school Name**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getHeadOfSchool( inSchoolName IN VARCHAR ) IS 
DECLARE
V_headOfSchool  school.headOfSchool%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT headOfSchool INTO v_headOfSchool FROM school WHERE schoolName = inSchoolName;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘The head of the school is ’||v_headOfSchool);
END;
/
```

It says compilation errors when I run it. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the DECLARE keyword.  That only applies for anonymous PL/SQL blocks.  With stored procedures the IS keyword marks the start of the declaration section.

The PL/SQL documentation provides a formal specification of the syntax and plenty of examples.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_procedure.htm#i2072424)

---

You could have solved this problem yourself by displaying the compilation error(s).  Modern IDEs like PLSQL Developer, SQL Developer or TOAD will do this automatically.  In SQL*Plus you can use the `show errors` command.  If you are using some other client you can run:

```
select * from user_errors
where name = 'GETHEADOFSCHOOL';
```

Notice that Oracle stores its object names in CAPITALS.  So CamelCase is all very well in the source code but the absence of underscores makes data dictionary lookups harder.